# How to save all selected messages into a folder with their categories and received time?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to select messages in Outlook then copy them into text files with the categories and received time as the txt titles. Example if three messages are selected, I would like three text files.

```vb
Sub selectMSGToText()

    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set oMail = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    Dim sMail As Object
    Set sMail = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    Dim categories As String: categories = oMail.categories
    Dim rtimeAs String: rtime= oMail.ReceivedTime

    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim path As String
    path = "D:\test\"
    Dim oFile As Object

    For Each oMail In sMail

        Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(path & categories & "|" & rtime & ".txt", True, True)
        oFile.WriteLine "test"
        oFile.Close
        Set fso = Nothing
        Set oFile = Nothing

    Next oMail

End Sub
```

I expect all selected messages to be in folder D:\test as distinct txt files with their own categories and received time as title.

Answer (score 0):

A `|` is not legal in a Windows file name, nor are the `/` or `\` or `:` you likely have in the `ReceivedTime` string.

Change to:

```
Dim rtime As Date: rtime= oMail.ReceivedTime
```

And use something like:

```
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(path & categories & "_" & Format$(rtime, "dd_mm_yy_hhmmss") & ".txt", True, True)
```

(This assumes `categories` will never contain illegal characters)

The 1st `true` you pass causes an existing file to be overwritten, so multiple emails received in the same second will be lost.

```
Set fso = Nothing
```

Needs to be outside the loop, else on the 2nd iteration it is `Nothing`.

Comment: Works fine for the receivedTime but the loop ain't working!

Comment: Any errors? Step through the code and check the paths.